# UIAutomation iOS: Picker wheel is invalid in the majority of test runs

Tags: ios, jenkins, ios-simulator, ios-ui-automation

I have written a large suit of tests with the UIAutomation API. The tests are launched by Jenkins and use Tuneup JS.

My problem is with picker wheels. A few tests encounter a picker wheel and will almost always fail because of an invalid element, `UIAElementNil`. I have tried using the recommended `target.pushTimeout()` to allow the test time to get a handle on the picker wheel element, and have had no luck with it.

Each test with a picker wheel pass sometimes (but rarely), so I'm pretty sure the code itself is not the issue.

Has anyone encountered similar issues with automation tests and picker wheels found a reason for, or solution to this problem?

```
target.pushTimeout(PICKER_WHEEL_DELAY);
rowTap(window.tableViews()[0], PRICE);

validField1 = false;
validField2 = false;

try {

    var picker = app.windows()[2].elements()[0].pickers()[0];
    if (picker.isValid()) {

        var wheel1 = picker.wheels()[0];
        var wheel2 = picker.wheels()[1];

        if (wheel1.isValid()){

            var pickedItems = wheel1.values();
            var nrOfItems = pickedItems.length;

            if (nrOfItems > 0 ) {
                wheel1.selectValue(MIN_PRICE_NEW_HOME);
                validField1 = true;
            }
        }

        if (wheel2.isValid()){

            pickedItems = wheel2.values();
            nrOfItems = pickedItems.length;

            if (nrOfItems > 0 ) {
                wheel2.selectValue(MAX_PRICE_NEW_HOME);
                validField2 = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(error) {
    UIALogger.logFail(error);
} finally {
    if (validField1 != true  || validField2 != true) {
        cleanUpAfterPickerFail(app);
        throw "failed: Couldnt find a valid picker wheel";
    }
}

app.windows()[2].elements()[0].toolbars()[0].buttons()["Done"].tap();
target.popTimeout();
```

Comment: I had problems with picker wheel, but please insert the part of your code where you access it, and the part of the log with the error message.

Comment: As I said in the question, the code has worked and the error happens when a picker wheel is invalid, Cannot perform action on invalid element: UIAElementNil. I will edit to include the code

Comment: Have you recently updated to XCode 5 and iOS 7?

Comment: No, haven't updated yet

Answer (score 1):

The only line where the exception can be thrown is the first in the `try` block:

```
var picker = app.windows()[2].elements()[0].pickers()[0];
```

You can introduce checks you've done below this using `isValid()`, but the best approach if you check again by the record button at the bottom if the wheels are accessible and the path is correct.

Comment: can you explain that better please? I don't see how this answers my question.

Comment: As I see, something is thrown an exception, because an action is trying to be performed on an invalid element. As you filtered all invalid element except the one in the quoted line above, this is the only place where the exception can be thrown. You can check it by writing to the log after each line. (No debug mode for instruments.)

As a solution, tap on the picker manually in record mode, and compare the recorded line with the quoted above. (If they equal, the `app` wariable can also be problematic.) Beware, there are two record buttons!